# learn python the hard way exercise 40 help

Tags: python

hey guys i am having trouble understanding this, i dont get when themap is referenced to the cities dict really. or the last line, what is the(cities, state) part?

thanks.

```
cities = { 'CA': 'San Francisco', 'MI': 'Detroit', 'FL': 'Jacksonville'}

cities['NY'] = 'New York'
cities['OR'] = 'Portland'

def find_city(themap, state):
    if state in themap:
        return themap[state]
    else:
        return 'not found'

#ok pay attention!
cities['_find'] = find_city

while True:
    print 'State? (ENTER to quit)'
    state = raw_input('> ')

    if not state: break

    #this line is the most important ever! study!
    city_found = cities['_find'] (cities, state)
    print city_found
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`cities['_find']` is exactly `find_city`. So `cities['_find'](cities, state)` is the same as `find_city(cities, state)`.

The reason for my first statement is this line:

```
cities['_find'] = find_city
```

That doesn't call `find_city`, it sticks the function itself in the dictionary. Python functions are just objects like lists and class instances. If you don't put parentheses after them, they can be assigned to variables.

Comment: @nmichaels of i get that thanks. but why is it cities['_find'] = find_city and not cities['_find'] = find_city()

Comment: @nmicheals If I understand you correctly, you're saying "The function `find_city` is in the `cities` map with the key `_find`?"

Comment: @neil because `find_city()` is the invocation of the function. `find_city` is the reference to the function.

Comment: @neil because find_city() would try to call the function (and so an error will be raised cause the functions accept two parameters)..and even if the function would not raise any error, cities['_find'] would hold the value returned by the function, not the reference to the function itself

Comment: @glowcoder Correct. YOu could make a dictionary, where each value is a function (This is a very useful feature, actually). To call the function, give the dictionary entry, and the arguments in brackets afterwards: `cities['_find'](cities, state)` would be calling `find_city(cities, state)`

Comment: @Ant: Good point. I elaborated. @TyrantWave: Yes! That's how we spell C's `switch` in Python.