# PYTHON codes with a lesson from a book

Tags: python, python-2.7

i'm reading zed shaw's book "learning python the hard way". Forgive me but i'm a newbie in coding, and i'm having a hard time understanding this. I can't seem to see how find_city function finds out what city to be returned by entering the state. The lines with" okay pay attention"  and" # this line is the most important ever! study! are the ones confusing me.

```
cities = {'CA': 'San Francisco', 'MI': 'Detroit',
                 'FL': 'Jacksonville'}

cities['NY'] = 'New York'
cities['OR'] = 'Portland'

def find_city(themap, state):
    if state in themap:
        return themap[state]
    else:
        return "Not found."

# ok pay attention!
cities['_find'] = find_city

while True:
    print "State? (ENTER to quit)",
    state = raw_input("> ")

    if not state: break

    # this line is the most important ever! study!
    city_found = cities['_find'](cities, state)
    print city_found
```

Comment: What *specifically* don't you understand? Update your question to explain.

Comment: As @ChrisMorgan said, you should edit your question, stating the specific parts you want explained since people don't know what to assume.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I already realized that and edited it :D

Comment: @aljon, you're new to SO, but here's a tip: do a [search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434740/learn-python-the-hard-way-exercise-40-help) before asking your question, and be really clear about what exactly you're confused about and what you've already tried. When people don't think you've put in any effort, they downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly:

- `cities` is instantiated as a dictionary, and some key/value are inserted here. Both key and values are string for CA -> San Francisco, MI -> Detroit, etc. etc.
- a function named `find_city` is defined, it takes two input parameters (`themap` and `state`);
- to the `cities` dictionary is added another key/value, where key is the string '_find' but, this time, the value is the function find_city and not a string as before;
- in the line `city_found = cities['_find'](cities, state)` you ask to the dictionary `cities` the value associated to the key '_find', that is the function `find_city`. Then, this function is called with the dictionary itself as first parameter and the 'state' read by the stdin as second parameter.

It would have been the same if it was written as:

```
method = cities['_find']
city_found = method(cities, state)
```

HTH

Comment: thank you Simon! It clears out already, but the raw input is placed in the variable state right? I don't see it being used elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, 'state' contains a string that's the raw input from stdin.

Comment: but i don't see it being used in other functions :(

Comment: state is used as input parameter for the find_city method.