# python underscores: learn python the hard way exercise 40

Tags: python, python-2.7

Iam trying to do the exercises in the book "Learn Python the hard way" page: 106. The example is below:

```
cities = {'CA': 'San Francisco', 'MI': 'Detroit', 'FL': 'Jacksonville'}

cities['NY'] = 'New York'
cities['OR'] = 'Portland'

def find_city(themap, state):
    if state in themap:
        return themap[state]
    else:
        return "Not found."

# ok pay attention!
cities['_find'] = find_city

while True:
    print "State? (ENTER to quit)",
    state = raw_input("> ")
    if not state: break

    # this line is the most important ever! study!
    city_found = cities['_find'](cities, state)
    print city_found
```

I do not understand what `cities['_find'] = find_city` does? What is `_find`? In particular, why the underscore? Similarly, I am not sure what `city_found = cities['_find'](cities, state)` does. I have seen a similar post on the same question:
[learn python the hard way exercise 40 help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434740/learn-python-the-hard-way-exercise-40-help)

which basically says that `cities['_find'] = find_city` adds the function find_city to the dictionary, but I still dont understand what `city_found = cities['_find'](cities, state)` does(?)

I'd really appreciate if someone could explain me the above two lines. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code:

```
cities['_find'] = find_city
```

simply inserts the function `find_city` into the `cities` dictionary, using the key `_find`. The underscore has no particular meaning, it's just part of the key string. Probably chosen to not collide with actual city names.

This code:

```
city_found = cities['_find'](cities, state)
```

Calls the `find_city` function, by first looking it up in the dictionary using the `_find` key.

It could be rewritten as:

```
city_found = find_city(cities, state)
```

There doesn't seem to be any real *point* in doing it like this, there's no benefit in having the dictionary (which is called a "map" in the code) contain the `find` function, that I can see.

Answer (score 3):

As you say, `cities['_find'] = find_city` adds the function to the dict. Accordingly, `cities['_find']` retrieves it from the dictionary.

`foo(a,b)` calls the function stored in `foo` with parameters `a` and `b`. `cities['_find'](cities, state)` does *the exact same thing*.

As to the underscore, it's just there so that it doesn't clash with a city called "find", should there be one. The whole example is highly contrived, but the point seems to be to teach you that functions are just objects.

Answer (score 1):

`cities['_find'] = find_city` adds the function to the dictionary. `city_found = cities['_find'](cities, state)` calls that function (since the parenteses and the two args, which the function `find_city` requires.

The underscore doesn't really change anything, it's part of the key. Normally you express something by using the underscore as prefix, like marking it as internally or something. The book should state somewhere, what it means by that.